# Cannot upload files bigger than 8GB to Amazon S3 by multi-part upload Java API due to broken pipe

Tags: upload, amazon-s3

I implemented S3 multi-part upload in Java, both high level and low level version, based on the sample code from 
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?HLuploadFileJava.html and http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?llJavaUploadFile.html

When I uploaded files of size less than 4 GB, the upload processes completed without any problem. When I uploaded a file of size 13 GB, the code started to show IO exception, broken pipes. After multiple retries, it still failed.

Here is the way to repeat the scenario. Take 1.1.7.1 release,

1. create a new bucket in US standard region
2. create a large EC2 instance as the client to upload file
3. create a file of 13GB in size on the EC2 instance.
4. run the sample code on either one of the high-level or low-level API S3 documentation pages from the EC2 instance
5. test either one of the three part size: default part size (5 MB) or set the part size to 100,000,000 or 200,000,000 bytes.

So far the problem shows up consistently. I did a tcpdump.  It appeared the HTTP server (S3 side) kept resetting the TCP stream, which caused the client side to throw IO exception - broken pipe, after the uploaded byte counts exceeding 8GB . Anyone has similar experiences when upload large files to S3 using multi-part upload?

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's not the case but maybe the storage is FAT32 formated just comes in my mind when you say "files less than 4GB work" --> http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm

Comment: Found the cause.  It is in the Java SDK 1.1.7.1 implementation. Please see this post on Amazon forum: [RepeatableFileInputStream skip() causes problem for large files >10GB: bug?] (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=62975&tstart=0)